# how to have multiple arguments in a input fuction in python

Tags: python

**This function throws an error at the input function claiming that the arguments are invalid.. any resolutions?**

```
def assignSquareValues():
        square=[[0,0,0],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0]]
        count=0
        try:
            for r in range(3):
                for c in range(3):
                    count+=1
                    print(count)
                    square[r][c]= int(input(("Enter a number(1-9) for square #",(count)+":",sep=''))) #this line throws an error stating that "TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2"

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            assignSquareValues()

        checkMagicSquare(square)
```

Comment: How are you calling the method? What is your exact error message? Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alec/Desktop/loShuMagicSquare.py", line 46, in <module>
    assignSquareValues()
  File "C:/Users/alec/Desktop/loShuMagicSquare.py", line 39, in assignSquareValues
    square[r][c]= int(input("Enter a number(1-9) for square #",(count)))#,":",sep="")))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: This is the error that i get..

Comment: actually after i added () around the arguments its just saying the separator argument is invalid syntax but i dont see anything wrong

Comment: That line is not correct. Can you please explain what it is you are trying to do? Explain what your code is supposed to do, explain what the line you are pointing to is supposed to do

Comment: add error in question , not in comment

Comment: the code is a Lo Shu Magic square project, i get integers for the 3x3 two dimensional list from the user, then the function "checkMagicSquare(square)" will send the list to a function that checks if the square is the Lo Shu Magic Square. And i got it all to work, but then i added the count argument within the input function to display the square which they are entering the number with the separator argument i began getting errors. currently the only error i am getting is invalid syntax at the sep="" argument

Comment: `input()` expects only one argument - displayed text - and you have three - text, `(count)+":"` and `sep=""`. `input()` doesn't work like `print()`. Concatenate all element into one text.

Comment: thanks for the help it works now!

Answer (score 1):

`input()` expects one argument - displayed text - so you have to concatenate all arguments in to one text

ie.

```
input("Enter a number(1-9) for square #" + str(count) + ":")
```

or

```
input("Enter a number(1-9) for square #{}:".format(count))
```